# Find average of inner lists List<List<Double>> using Stream and return result as List<Double> consist of averages of inner list

Tags: java, java-stream

have come across one scenario where am not sure how to use Stream to get the desired result.

```
List<List<Double>> list =
    Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList(3.0), Arrays.asList(9.0, 20.0), Arrays.asList(15.0, 7.0));
```

Want to convert the above into

```
List<Double> result = [3.0, 14.5, 11.0] ;
```

need to calculate average of each inner List and store in result.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried?

Comment: @AndyTurner
I tried with below code 

    `List<Double> resultNew = list.stream()
            .map(a -> a.stream().mapToDouble(x -> x).average())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());`
i didn't pay attention to that inside map when mapToDouble with aggregate method is used it returns Optional.

Answer (score 1):

in order not to have to deal with the optional you can instead use `Collectors.averagingDouble`

```
List<List<Double>> list = Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList(3.0), Arrays.asList(9.0, 20.0), Arrays.asList(15.0, 7.0));

List<Double> resut = list.stream()
                         .map(t -> t.stream().collect(Collectors.averagingDouble(Double::doubleValue)))
                         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```